# What are these fibers coming out from the baseboard?

Tags: wood, baseboard

house built in the 50s. I notice these broken off from the baseboard(?). Any idea what they are? They don't look like wood and I don't know if the white structure is part of the baseboard or something else. Thanks ahead

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is wood or fiberboard.  What you've got there is water damage and dry rot.

Comment: That's mdf you can tell from how it has swollen from the bottom up.  wood doesn't swell that way.

Comment: Indeed this is MDF that got wet. Either someone dumped water on the carpet, or there's a leak somewhere.

Comment: Or the dog had an "accident" there.

Comment: Thank you. The previous persons have dogs, yes. So if it's dry now, is it safe to assume there is no ongoing leak?

Comment: @Motoko We can only see not-repaired water damage.  No way for us to determine if it will stay dry.